# What is this IC? AY7397

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I'm trying to identify this IC. It's on the motherboard of an Epson 5040UB 4K HD projector. The projector tries to boot and then shuts off after 4 mins. A flir thermal image of the MB during this boot sequence shows IC 4706 at 204°F hot. I'm looking to replace this IC, but I cannot identify it. The printed marking on the IC is "AY 7397"

**UPDATE**: *[according to user Diah on badcaps.net forum](https://www.badcaps.net/forum/showthread.php?t=86943):*

> AY are DC to DC PWM (Pulse-width modulation) step down. with easy
> language of my...the boot didn't receive signal LAMP ON, it will not
> step down. it keep on high pulse ( FAN High SPEED ) ( ERROR BLINKING )
> this why they become warm.

So, perhaps the problem is with the ballast and this chip is operating as expected within tolerance and just heating up because its holding the load until the shutdown occurs? If so, would its twin IC4707 not exhibit similar thermal reaction?

[image: It's IC 4706 in this picture]

[image: The markings on the IC are shown here "AY7397"]

Comment: Hmm hard one to find, I suspect its either a Regulator, power switch or transistor. Can’t think what AY would stand for, not aware of any brands that use that ID. Can you measure the voltage on the various pins? That might help pin down its purpose.

Comment: Update I've found Microchip have a few ICs marked with ID AY0438. It's possibly a Microchip component.

Comment: I'm not much help with your question, but did you have any luck repairing this projector? I have the same issue. I've tested out the power supply and ballast and no luck. Was this component the solution?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like an Rohm [BD2242G-GTR](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/power_switch/bd2242g-e.pdf)  Adjustable Current Limit High Side Switch

[image]

Comment: +1. The marking matches. The board layout and the pin connections kinda fit. Interestingly, couldn't see any resistor connected to the ILIM pin that shouldn't be left floating.

Comment: Back of the board?

Comment: Could be. The board has a lot of space though.

Comment: Datasheet says the resistor should be as close as possible, so maybe that conflicted with wide power traces on the top. Just guessing.

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right.